# UsefieldArray react hook form deleting the last element only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I'm having a trouble with react hook form usefield array. Basically I'm trying to append and delete but the problem is when I'm deleting its deleting only the last element.
append is working fine but suppose if I have 3 fields with values a,b,c and I want to remove b, when I'm pressing remove button of b then its removing c, if I try to remove a again its also removing c only from the UI.

Here is my codesandbox link for the code:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-sxfmhs?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some changes to your codesandbox and this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Controller, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import "./styles.css";

let renderCount = 0;

function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      parameters: [{ parameterName: "" }]
    }
  });

  const {
    fields: parameterfields,
    append: appendParameters,
    remove: removeParameters
  } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "parameters"
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  // if you want to control your fields with watch
  // const watchResult = watch("test");
  // console.log(watchResult);

  // The following is useWatch example
  // console.log(useWatch({ name: "test", control }));

  renderCount++;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Field Array </h1>
      <p>The following demo allow you to delete, append, prepend items</p>
      <span className="counter">Render Count: {renderCount}</span>
      <ul>
        {parameterfields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={item.id}
              style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: 30 }}
            >
              <div style={{ width: "90%", marginRight: 20 }}>
                <Controller
                  name={`parameters.${index}.parameterName`}
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <div>
                      {console.log(item.parameterName)}
                      <input
                        name={`parameters[${index}].parameterName`}
                        variant="standard"
                        InputProps={{
                          disableUnderline: true
                        }}
                        // className={styles.title}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        defaultValue={item.parameterName}
                        placeholder="Parameter Name"
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <button
                  onClick={() => removeParameters(index)}
                  sx={{ width: 130, height: 50 }}
                  variant="outlined"
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <section>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            appendParameters({ 
              date: new Date(),
              parameterName: "" });
          }}
        >
          append
        </button>
      </section>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Its working man. But I didn't get it where was the problem? You have added date on append, why?

Comment: the problem was: 1 you need the key and two the input {`parameters[${index}].parameterName`} <-- is a array this is the correct way

Answer (score 9):

// ✅ correct:
{fields.map((field, index) => <input key={field.id} ... />)}

// ❌ incorrect:
{fields.map((field, index) => <input key={index} ... />)}

This will solve the Problem

For more Go there: https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

Answer (score 3):

**I resolved :)).**

I update key to: key={item.id} => resolve . I think it's required

> parameterfields.map((item, index) => {
> return (
> <div
> **key={item.id}**
> style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: 30 }}
> >

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).